# angularjs controller in directive using controllerAs can not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to put some data in the scope which my directive create. Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scarletsky/JNga3/1/).

the following code works well

```
.directive('directive1', function () {
    return: {
        scope: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = 'world';
        }
    }
})

<div directive1>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
</div>
```

but these code do not work

```
.directive('directive2', function () {
    return: {
        scope: true,
        controller: function () {
            this.name = 'world';
        },
        controllerAs: 'testCtrl'
    }
})

<div directive2>
    <p>{{ testCtrl.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? or did I misunderstand something about `controllerAs`?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that. You defined controller without `$scope`. What is `controllerAs`?

Comment: @MaximShoustin [angular1.2 docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), a new feature for directive

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ControllerAs support for directives [was added in 1.2.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120rc1-spooky-giraffe-2013-08-13), so you'll have to use most recent version, instead of `1.0.2` from linked fiddle. [This way](http://jsfiddle.net/JNga3/2/) it works like you wanted.

Comment: You are right. After migrating to angular 1.2, it works well. thanks~!

Answer (score -1):

Please do not confuse with directive controller and a normal controller! So yea, a directve can have a controller, which controls something. But it's not equivalent to a normal controller!

There isn't actually a problem to put directive logic into directive controller, but the directive controller actually, is used for cross directive communication. A controller instance of one directive can be injected into another directive which sits on the same element (or child elements).

The "controller as" expression is for normal controllers. So just do your self a favour and put your logic into directives link function.

Comment: Thanks for the detail of controller! Actually I am confusing with a normal controller and directive controller. Thanks again!

Comment: This answer is misleading - a directive controller **is** the same as a normal controller, except that instead of being instantiated by the `ngController` directive, it's instantiated by the directive you associate it with. It works just the same, injectables, `controllerAs`, everything. 

Logic can/should go in a directive's controller - the link function should primarily be used for DOM manipulation.